# Android RecyclerView элемент занимает всю высоту экрана

Tags: java, android

Ожидаю получить что-то такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А получаю такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ActivityMain

```
    package com.trr.evan.teststssss;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] myDataset = getDataSet();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        // если мы уверены, что изменения в контенте не изменят размер layout-а RecyclerView
        // передаем параметр true - это увеличивает производительность
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // используем linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        // создаем адаптер
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    private String[] getDataSet() {

        String[] mDataSet = new String[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            mDataSet[i] = "item" + i;
        }
        return mDataSet;
    }

}
```

Adapter

```
    package com.trr.evan.teststssss;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by avtor on 20.03.2018.
 */

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    // класс view holder-а с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент
    // отдельного пункта списка
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // наш пункт состоит только из одного TextView
        public TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_recycler_item);
        }
    }

    // Конструктор
    public RecyclerAdapter(String[] dataset) {
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    // Создает новые views (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        // тут можно программно менять атрибуты лэйаута (size, margins, paddings и др.)

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Заменяет контент отдельного view (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }

    // Возвращает размер данных (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

activity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.trr.evan.teststssss.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item"
            android:text="hello_world"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас на экране ровно то, что в разметке. У ячейки списка высота поставлена `match_parent`, засим она равняется высоте контейнера, вмещающего ячейку, т.е высоте экрана.

Вам надо, видимо, заменить высоту на `wrap_content`